# Click in Vanilla HTML vs Click in Puppeteer Differences and why does it work in later

Tags: javascript, selenium, web-scraping, automated-tests, puppeteer

I am trying to automate few items on Google and LinkedIn (As a test) and it is hard to figure out why this code actually does not work in vanilla .

```
document.getElementsByClassName("search-global-typeahead__input always-show-placeholder")[0].click()
```

but the same relevant from puppeteer or selenium (both using webdriver)

```
await page.click('input...')
```

Actually works.

What is it the webdriver does differently? Why does it fail in vanilla? Is it because click is accompanied by many other events. Does the underlying webdriver send all these?

The src code 
[Puppeteer click src code](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/caaf4d2086036d4bf201587529dd3e3b38b6f9c6/experimental/puppeteer-firefox/lib/JSHandle.js#L329)

actually does not anything more than just normal click - invoking mouse.

1. Am I missing something?
2. Is there a webdriver kinda JS vanilla library?

Comment: What do you mean "does not work" is `getElementsByClassName` throwing an error or is just nothing happening?

Comment: It's possible that a standard javascript click only generates a click event.  WebDriver generates many more events.  See here for details:  https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#element-click

Comment: @Jortega click is not invoked. In the inspect mode, you can see that the event is actually raised but the button click does not happen.

Comment: Puppeteer click involves a lot: scrolling into view, moving the mouse to a point in the element, pressing the mouse, optionally delaying or multi-clicking, then releasing the mouse. Native JS `.click()` just fires the event without scroll or mouse involved. Please share a [mcve] of the page you're manipulating -- there's no real way to say what the problem might be in this case without some sort of runnable code and the target website.